# Floating Point error when computing Binomial Distribution Probability

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I have been given a binomial distribution:
$$B(m+n;n,p)=\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}p^mq^n.$$

Here $m = 10^3$, $n=10^2$, $p=10^{-2}$, $q=1-p.$

I'm using MATLAB to compute log $B(m+n;n,p)$ and store the value in **logB**

```
m=10^3;
n=10^2;
p=10^(-2);
q=1-p;
logB=log(factorial(m+n)/(factorial(m)*factorial(n))*p^m*q^n)
```

I get **logB** as NaN . How can I modify the formula to avoid floating point error and get a valid answer?

Comment: Taking those factorials is probably giving you infinities, the division of which gives you NaN. You need a factorial division function which preemptively cancels.

Comment: You have a ratio of a product of $n$ terms by a product of $n$ terms. Write this as the product of $n$ ratios, each of which should of moderate size.

Comment: @Richard I'm trying to simplify but still stuck: ((m+n)(m+n-1)...(m+1))/n!

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth could you elaborate a bit? Thanks.

Comment: You want to compute $\frac{abc}{def}$ where both enumerator and denominator end up very large numbers. So compute it as $\frac ad\cdot  \frac be \cdot \frac cf$ where now each fraction is of moderate size.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why [`gammaln`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gammaln.html) exists

`logB = gammaln(m+n+1) - gammaln(m+1) - gammaln(n+1) + m*log(p) + n*log(q);`